# Reduce taking long time on six equations

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, series-expansion

I have a system of equations, 4 linear and 2 quadratic, of the following form:

$$L_{i,j}(x_1, \cdots, x_{12}) = \sum_{k=1}^{12} x_k c_{k,i,j}$$

for $i, j = 1, 2$, i.e. the $L_{i,j}$ are the equations linear in $x_1, \cdots, x_{12}$, and

$$Q_j(x_1, \cdots, x_{12}) = \sum_{i=2}^{11} X_{i,j}Y_{i+1,j} - Y_{i,j}X_{i+1,j}$$

for $j = 1, 2$ and where

$$X_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} x_kc_{k,1,j}, \quad Y_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^{i-1} x_kc_{k,2,j}.$$

I have currently implemented these equations via:

```
l11 = Sum[x[k]c11[k], {k, 1, 12}]
l21 = Sum[x[k]c21[k], {k, 1, 12}]
l12 = Sum[x[k]c12[k], {k, 1, 12}]
l22 = Sum[x[k]c22[k], {k, 1, 12}]
q1 = Sum[Sum[x[k]c11[k], {k, 1, i-1}]Sum[x[k]c21[k], {k, 1, i}] 
     - Sum[x[k]c11[k], {k, 1, i}]Sum[x[k]c21[k], {k, 1, i-1}], {k, 2, 11}]
q2 = Sum[Sum[x[k]c12[k], {k, 1, i-1}]Sum[x[k]c22[k], {k, 1, i}] 
     - Sum[x[k]c12[k], {k, 1, i}]Sum[x[k]c22[k], {k, 1, i-1}], {k, 2, 11}]
```

I then would like to solve the system

```
Reduce[l11 == a1 && l12 == a2 && l21 == a3 && l22 == a4 && q1 == a5 && q2 == a6,
{x[7], x[8], x[9], x[10], x[11], x[12]}]
```

in as much generality as possible. This should just be 4 linears and 2 quadratics, but it's taking an absurd amount of time and I'm not sure whether it will even finish.

My main question is: how do I speed this up? (If possible.) Also, I'm actually interested in asymptotic series expansions of the solutions near $x_k = 1$, i.e. suppose $x_i = 1 + \kappa_i\delta$ for $i = 1, \cdots, 6$ and constants $\kappa_i$, and then see what $x_i$ expands into for $i = 7, \cdots, 12$, so if one has any suggestions (which might be faster than Reduce) there that'd also be welcome! (I gave AsymptoticSeries a shot but after a while it just spat out the same inputs.)

I'll add that for my parameters $c_{k,i,j}$ and some initial values of $x_i$ for $i = 1, \cdots, 6$ close to $1$, NSolve gives four solutions (of $x_7, \cdots, x_{12}$), the last of which is close to 1. (Same goes for FindRoot.)

Comment: I think you need to evaluate the coefficients of the system under consideration. BTW, your  $\LaTeX$ notations are not in accordance with your notations in Wolfram Language.

Comment: Thanks - I've since updated it to be consistent. I cannot evaluate the coefficients - as far as I can tell, it would be more complicated than allowing the coefficients to be nicely encoded as above. If I fix $x_1, \cdots, x_6$ and then solve backwards, for $x_7, x_8, x_9$ then $x_{10}$ through the last linear equation, the solution for $x_{10}$ in terms of $x_{11}, x_{12}$ is a fraction and the numerator apparently has 758 terms.

Comment: It seems you can set $x_1,\ldots,x_6$ to zero without loosing generality. Can you get a solution in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm interested in a solution for $x_1, \cdots, x_{12}$ in a neighbourhood of 1, which means I can't get rid of simplifying these coefficients. Thanks for the suggestion